# How To Access Value Of A Function Called In Main

Tags: haskell

So I'm a beginner from Haskell, I ran a function that outputs a list of tuples in main, is there a way to access that list of tuples without using Monad in another function so I could check if that list of tuples contains certain element? Or do I really need to use Monad for that? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jane. Welcome to SO. Please provide the Haskell code you wrote, and the things that you have tried so far, so as we can correct you.

Comment: Yes, pass it as a parameter.  `main = do { tuplelist <- makeListOfTuples;  let result = otherFunction tuplelist;  print result }`.  Here `otherFunction` is pure, the IO monad is confined to `main`.

Comment: You don't need to use a monad to scan a list -- you could, but you should not: it would make a simple thing more complex. Either exploit library functions like `elem`, or define your own helper pure functions which scan the list using recursion and pattern matching.

Comment: @luqui That should be an answer, not a comment! (I admit answering that way is risky given the dearth of details available so far, but if you're gonna write that particular risky response you might as well put it in the answer box.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, pass it as a parameter.  For example

```
otherFunction :: Eq t => [(t, t)] -> Bool
otherFunction tuplelist = and [ x == y | (x,y) <- tuplelist ]

main = do
   tuplelist <- makeListOfTuples
   let result = otherFunction tuplelist
   print result
```

Here `otherFunction` is completely pure, yet it can depends on data that was made in `IO`.